# Find the 10 top most occurring strings in a huge array of objects

Tags: algorithms, space-complexity, streaming-algorithm

Find the 10 top most occurring strings in a huge array of Strings.

Since the array is huge, it is not possible to load it in memory completely.
My idea is to parse the arrays one by one and put the strings in a hash table with string as key and occurrence count as value. But this would take too much memory.

Is there any other optimized solution? Given that we only care about top 10 keys.

Comment: Your question is poorly written. The title is a very clear question by
itself. But the text of the question has no (single) string, but many
arrays of objects (whatever that may be: symbols, symbol strings, ...?).
There seem to be an undecipherable confusion between the statement of
the otiginal problem and your attempt at a specific solution which may
or may not be workable. Asking questions properly is the first step
towards answering them, either by people who help you, or by yourself.
I also assume you meant to say: "... hash table with objects as keys
and occurrence counts as values ...".

Comment: [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/finding-the-element-that-occurs-the-most-in-a-very-large-file) looks related, or even a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

One optimized way is a streaming algorithm given by Charikar, Chen and Farach-Colton, known as *CountSketch*. See

- [Finding Frequent Items in Data Streams](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45465-9_59), ICALP 2002

It takes logarithmic space (in the size of your input), and gives an approximation for the $k$ most-frequent elements in that input. $k$ is an input parameter, that also affects the memory in use.

There are also extensions for sliding windows algorithms, and to other ways of measuring which element is considered "frequent".